# What is the alternative solutions for SQL server agent on shared hosting

Tags: sql-server, shared-hosting, sql-server-agent

I host my application and SQL database on shared hosting and I want to run SQL jobs but SQL server agent is not available on shared hosting .

What is the way of accomplishing this ?
Or recommendations for shared hosting company allow SQL server agent?

Comment: You will probably need to expose a web service in your shared hosting, then on another machine to run a scheduler either crontab on linux paired with a shell script and cURL, or in windows, set a task in task scheduler paired with a bat file an also cURL

Comment: Talk to your shared hosting company. They charge extra but they do allow sql server agent jobs.